# Is it possible our new tire fitting has had something do with leaking coolant?

Tags: jeep, coolant-leak

We just got front passenger tire replaced on jeep Cherokee and now car is losing coolant like crazy. We have looked under the hood & looks like the damage is in this same area. There was no leak prior but was hoping someone could plse give an idea of likelihood that this can occur (fitting / putting on hoist etc). The guys that fitted the tires are good blokes & have done stuff for us before however it seems a bit of a coincidence to have happened directly after & any knowledge to go in & talk to them about would be much appreciated as on bones of butt & cant afford to fix something they have damaged, if they have.  Thanks for your help & pic for reference :)[image][image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: IMHO whether the car was on a ramp or on a jack - neither will have affected your cooling system. This is likely to be coincidence.

Comment: Thanks for replying! :) is hard to see in the pic & my explanation is terrible but it looks from what we can see that the pipe has been hit / broken which has caused the leak & was wondering if when they jacked it up it either wasn't sitting "just right" or they could have accidentally smashed it.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Are you certain that's coolant?  That seems to be an odd color for a Jeep.  Check power steering and ATF first.

Comment: @SteveRacer new jeeps use hybrid oat fluid which is red/orange/pink. The ps fluid is clear, for an electric pump i forget exactly, mineral oil maybe. It could be atf but the staining in the first few pics suggests coolant.

Comment: I sit correctificated.

Answer (score 2):

While it is *really* hard to tell from the pictures, I'd suggest your analysis could be spot on. If the mechanic who fitted the front tire jacked the vehicle up from the area where the leak is occurring, I can see where a coolant leak would ensue. It appears from the pictures, the area where your are pointing to the leak is at the bottom of the radiator or possibly the core support. If they jacked it up from there, it certainly could have cause a crack in the cooling system, which would then dump coolant. Now, we don't know if that's what they did, but I'm suggesting it *is possible* that it could happen. You may want to tread carefully with the shop and not go in guns blazing, but rather, ask a manager the same way you asked here if this is at all possible.